# Условия для if и else

Tags: java, if

Хочу создать условия для вывода информации о пассажирах:

1. Не может быть меньше нуля.
2. Если равняется нулю то автобус пуст.
3. Не может быть больше вместимости автобуса.

Но не могу установить третье условие, так как после его установки, при проверке двух других, возникает текст который должен быть только при 3 условии.

```
package programm;

public class Programm {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
       Avtobus bus = new Avtobus("Calculator");

        bus.setName(666);                  //Номер автобуса
        bus.setNumberOfPassengers(50);     //Количество пассажиров
        bus.setCostOfTravel(30);           //Цена поездки
        bus.setNumberOfStops(10);          //Количество Остановок
        bus.setTheCapacityOfTheBus(50);    //Вместимость автобуса


        bus.Stopped();                  //Остановка
        bus.info1();                    //Первая остановка.Осталось остановок            
        bus.info2();                    //Кол-во пассажиров
        bus.NumberOfAvailableSeats();   //Кол-во свободных мест
        bus.info3();                    //Прибыль с одной остановки
        bus.CalculationOfProfit();      //Подсчет конечной прибыли




package newobject;

public class Avtobus {

    private int Name;
    private int NumberOfPassengers;
    private int CostOfTravel;
    private int NumberOfStops;
    private int TheCapacityOfTheBus;
    private String Calculator;


protected Avtobus(){

}    
public Avtobus(String Calculator) {

this.Calculator = Calculator;

on();

}

public Avtobus(int Name, int NumberOfPassengers, int CostOfTravel, int NumberOfStops, int TheCapacityOfTheBus){

this.Name = Name;

this.NumberOfPassengers = NumberOfPassengers;

this.CostOfTravel = CostOfTravel;

this.NumberOfStops = NumberOfStops;

this.TheCapacityOfTheBus = TheCapacityOfTheBus;

}




public int getNumberOfPassengers(){

return NumberOfPassengers;

}

public void setNumberOfPassengers(int nNumberOfPassengers){

if (nNumberOfPassengers<0){

System.out.println("!!Количество пассажиров не может быть меньше нуля!!");

}else{

NumberOfPassengers = nNumberOfPassengers;

}

if(nNumberOfPassengers ==0){

System.out.println("Автобус пуст");    

}else{

NumberOfPassengers = nNumberOfPassengers;    

}

if(nNumberOfPassengers>TheCapacityOfTheBus){

System.out.println("!!Количество пассажиров не может быть больше чем вместимость 
автобуса!! ");       

}

}
```

Comment: Анатолий, отформатируйте код нормально, вставьте его текстом а не картинками.

Comment: Если нужен весь код, я его скину. Я новичок, не бросайтесь камнями, буду рад помощи, так как зашел в тупик.

Comment: Владимир Клыков, сделал

Comment: @АнатолийМихеенко советую назвать объект автобуса `bus`, а не `avt`

Comment: @АнатолийМихеенко так же метка netbeans тут не причем, у вас же проблема не из за nb, а из за кода. Я удалил эту метку.

Comment: Anton238, понял, сейчас изменю, а не могли бы вы сказать, почему лучше bus чем avt?

Comment: @АнатолийМихеенко так же метка netbeans тут не причем, у вас же проблема не из за nb, а из за кода. Я удалил эту метку.

Comment: Anton238, спасибо за исправления, я признателен

Comment: @АнатолийМихеенко тем что 1)так понятнее что это автобус, лучше для читабельности кода(bus по англ это автобус если что) 2)avt ассоциируется с awt, а это библиотека в java

Comment: Anton238, понял, я слышал что нужно выбирать названия более ассоциирующиеся с тем что они описывают, в дальнейшем буду к этому повнимательнее, спасибо за объяснения

Comment: @АнатолийМихеенко так bus более ассоциируется с avtobus чем avt. Если у вас спросить, что такое avt, вы не сможете ответить, а если спросить что так bus, то вы скажете что это автобус. Да и к тому же не очень правильная практика называть имена транскриптом( я про avtobus), и обычно имена переменных делаются такими же как и названия классов, на которые они ссылаются(`Avtobus avtobus = new Avtobus();`).

Comment: Anton238, Хорошо, учту, спасибо за подсказки

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Иногда применение оператора `return` даже в `void` методах помогает избежать множественных `if else` и сделать код с условиями гораздо более читаемым.

```
public void setNumberOfPassengers(int nNumberOfPassengers){
    // первое негативное условие - метод работать не может
    if (nNumberOfPassengers < 0) {
        System.out.println("!!Количество пассажиров не может быть меньше нуля!!");
        return;
    } 

    // второе негативное условие - метод работать не может
    if (nNumberOfPassengers == 0) {
        System.out.println("Автобус пуст");
        return;    
    }

    // третье негативное условие - метод работать не может
    if (nNumberOfPassengers > TheCapacityOfTheBus) {
        System.out.println("!!Количество пассажиров не может быть больше чем вместимость автобуса!!");
        return;       
    } 

    // если мы не вывалились из метода в одной из предыдущих проверок
    // выполняем основную работу метода
    NumberOfPassengers = nNumberOfPassengers;
    System.out.println("Ты угадал сколько человек может быть в автобусе! Как #%$# ты это сделал?!! оО");
}
```

Любое условие, дающее однозначный результат работы метода можно снабжать собственным `return`.

Answer (score 4):

Кроме `else` есть еще `else if`:

```
public void setNumberOfPassengers(int nNumberOfPassengers)
{
  if (nNumberOfPassengers < 0)
  {
    System.out.println("!!Количество пассажиров не может быть меньше нуля!!");
  } 
  else if (nNumberOfPassengers == 0)
  {
    System.out.println("Автобус пуст");    
  }
  else if (nNumberOfPassengers > TheCapacityOfTheBus)
  {
    System.out.println("!!Количество пассажиров не может быть больше чем вместимость автобуса!!");       
  } 
  else 
  {
    NumberOfPassengers = nNumberOfPassengers;
  }
}
```

---

Kоличество пассажиров Вы устанавливаете *до того*, как задаете вместимость:

```
    bus.setNumberOfPassengers(50);     //Количество пассажиров
    ...
    bus.setTheCapacityOfTheBus(50);    //Вместимость автобуса
```

а надо - *после*:

```
    ...
    bus.setTheCapacityOfTheBus(50);    //Вместимость автобуса
    bus.setNumberOfPassengers(50);     //Количество пассажиров
```

Comment: Хм, красиво, про else if не знал, не знал что можно их так использовать, это многое упрощает, но проблема в том, что при вводе значения  в    bus.setNumberOfPassengers   к примеру 50 при том, что   bus.setTheCapacityOfTheBus   является тоже 50 выходит сообщение 
  System.out.println("!!Количество пассажиров не может быть больше чем вместимость автобуса!!");   которого быть не должно, так как проверка проходиться, так как количество пассажиров не больше вместимости автобуса, а она ровна ей

Comment: @АнатолийМихеенко Это маловероятно. Скорее всего дело в том, что количество пассажиров Вы устанавливаете *до того*, как задаете вместимость.

Comment: Igor, что вы имеете в виду, вы про про установку значений в bus.setNumberOfPassengers(); и bus.setNumberOfPassengers(); ? или про реализацию самих условия и их расположения в коде?

Comment: Хм, это и вправду помогло, поменять их местами то есть bus.setNumberOfPassengers();  и  bus.setNumberOfPassengers(); но меня терзает любопытство, почему это помогло?

Comment: @АнатолийМихеенко В реальном мире что известно раньше - вместимость автобуса или количество пассажров?

Comment: Igor вместимость автобуса, стоило самому догадаться, спасибо за подсказку

Answer (score 0):

Попробую предложить такой дизайн кода:

```
int busCapacity;
int numberOfPassenger;

public void setNumberOfPassengers(int amount){

    if ((amount < 0)||( busCapacity < amount))
        System.out.println("ERROR");
    else if (amount == 0)
        System.out.println("Bus is empty");
    else
        numberOfPassenger = amount;
}
```